# Couldn't use SELECT in including Unicode characters table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, bulkinsert, string-conversion

I used Bulk Insert to import data from a text:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Infosp1 FROM  'D:\test.txt' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR =',', ROWTERMINATOR  ='\n', DATAFILETYPE='widechar')
```

This is my 'D:\test.txt'(saved by Endcoding : Unicode ):

> BácHồng,Giá,3
>
> BácHồng,Hành,2
>
> BácHồng,Lơxanh,3
>
> BácHồng,Xả,3
>
> BácHồng,Ngao,5
>
> BácHồng,Bắptàu,5
>
> CôHòaBính,Giá,5
>
> CôHòaBính,Càrốt,2
>
> CôHòaBính,Chanh,2

[---->This is my table. Click to show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5VcJ.png)

Why using INSERT shows 0 result??????:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Infosp1 WHERE Khach = 'BácHồng'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Infosp1 WHERE Khach = 'CôHòaBính'
```

---I think that have some problems around convertion data type because save this 'D:\test.txt' by Endcoding : ANSI have some errors like :

> BácH?ng, CôH?aBính. In other case, when my field didn't error type i could use `SELECT` to show all results.  I want have a solve could make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Try prepending `N` to unicode string literals in SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Infosp1 WHERE Khach = N'BácHồng'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Infosp1 WHERE Khach = N'CôHòaBính'
```

---

Example:

```
create table Infosp1 (Khach nvarchar(64), FirstName nvarchar(64), SomeNumber int)
insert into Infosp1 values 
 (N'BácHồng',N'Giá',3)
,(N'BácHồng',N'Hành',2)
,(N'BácHồng',N'Lơxanh',3)
,(N'BácHồng',N'Xả',3)
,(N'BácHồng',N'Ngao',5)
,(N'BácHồng',N'Bắptàu',5)
,(N'CôHòaBính',N'Giá',5)
,(N'CôHòaBính',N'Càrốt',2)
,(N'CôHòaBính',N'Chanh',2)

SELECT 'WithN' as WithOrWithoutN, * FROM dbo.Infosp1 WHERE Khach = N'BácHồng'   
union all
SELECT 'WithoutN',* FROM dbo.Infosp1 WHERE Khach = 'BácHồng'   
union all 
SELECT 'WithN', * FROM dbo.Infosp1 WHERE Khach = N'CôHòaBính'  
union all
SELECT 'WithoutN',* FROM dbo.Infosp1 WHERE Khach = 'CôHòaBính'
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WSNNX6950

returns:

```
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| WithOrWithoutN |   Khach   | FirstName | SomeNumber |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| WithN          | BácHồng   | Giá       |          3 |
| WithN          | BácHồng   | Hành      |          2 |
| WithN          | BácHồng   | Lơxanh    |          3 |
| WithN          | BácHồng   | Xả        |          3 |
| WithN          | BácHồng   | Ngao      |          5 |
| WithN          | BácHồng   | Bắptàu    |          5 |
| WithN          | CôHòaBính | Giá       |          5 |
| WithN          | CôHòaBính | Càrốt     |          2 |
| WithN          | CôHòaBính | Chanh     |          2 |
| WithoutN       | CôHòaBính | Giá       |          5 |
| WithoutN       | CôHòaBính | Càrốt     |          2 |
| WithoutN       | CôHòaBính | Chanh     |          2 |
+----------------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```